# Do I need to worry about Process in foreach loop

Tags: c#, process, garbage-collection

Here is the piece of code, which run through all the process and when It finds the right process, code sends the message. My question is what happened to the 'proc', how to dispose that process.

```
//get all other (possible) running instances
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();            
        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName.ToLower() == ProcessName.ToLower())
            {
                SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, (uint)Message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }               
        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Harsha

Comment: You can be explicit about case insensitive string comparisons with the `Equals` method: `if (proc.ProcessName.Equals(ProcessName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957320/what-does-process-dispose-actually-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general terms you don't need to worry about disposing or deallocating objects, *unless* the object implements the `IDisposable` interface. If it does you should either call the `Dispose()` method on it manually when you're finished, or wrap with a `using` statement to have it called automatically:

```
using (var disposableObject = new DisposableType())
{
    // do work with disposableObject
}
```

Comment: although in this case, the code quoted probably isn't marking the end of life for the processes, and so should leave them undisposed.

Comment: The `using` statement is of little help in this case because `GetProcesses` does all the instantiation.

Comment: @Massif: Dipsosing the Process object will NOT close the process, but only your handle to the same. Missing to dispose the handle will waste unmanaged resources until the GC will collect your Process object.

Answer (score 7):

To make sure all resoucers are freed as early as possible, call Dispose on the process, when you no longer need it.

```
//get all other (possible) running instances
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
try
{
    foreach (Process proc in processes)
    {
    // use proc
    }
}
finally
{
    foreach (Process proc in processes)
        proc.Dispose();
    processes = null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

IF you are looping to find your won process then you could try something like:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

In any case I would change it to:

```
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (proc.ProcessName.ToLower() == ProcessName.ToLower())
        {
            SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, (uint)Message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }               
    }
```

That way no variable will refernce the "GetProcesses" and the GC would eventually handle it.

Comment: this will lock the ressources until the GC is run.

Answer (score -3):

The variable `proc` is local to the foreach loop so once the loop completes, it will automatically be garbage collected.

Comment: wont help against dangling resources until the GC will run