# What does Process.Dispose() actually do?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

In C# `class Process` inherits from `class Component` that implements `IDisposable` and so I can call `Dispose()` on any `Process` object. Do I really have to? How do I know if I really have to?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
 var allProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
 var processesNames = processes.Select( p => p.ProcessName );
 // output process names here
```

Now it looks like I have an array of `Process` objects and I have craft a `try-finally` to traverse the array and `Dispose()` each object. That's definitely lots of extra code.

What does that `Dispose()` do for `Process` objects? Do I really need to `Dispose()` every `Process` object and how do I decide if I need to do so?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Do I really need to `Dispose()` every `Process` object and how do I decide if I need to do so?

Yes, you should dispose them. Note this text in the documentation for [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx):

> A system process is uniquely identified on the system by its process identifier. Like many Windows resources, a process is also identified by its handle, which might not be unique on the computer. A handle is the generic term for an identifier of a resource. The operating system persists the process handle, which is accessed through the Handle property of the Process component, even when the process has exited. Thus, you can get the process's administrative information, such as the ExitCode (usually either zero for success or a nonzero error code) and the ExitTime. Handles are an extremely valuable resource, so leaking handles is more virulent than leaking memory.

So if you don't `Dispose` them, you're potentially leaking the handles (until they're garbage collected - but the whole point of `Dispose` is to allow early cleanup of resources)

---

Note, also, that the same documentation indicates that `Process` overrides `Dispose(bool)` - another clue that it actually does *something* when `Dispose` is called.

Comment: I would love a `using (IEnumerable<IDisposable> ...)` here :)

Comment: @eFloh - not sure what you're aiming for there. A `using` statement introduces a new variable and a scope in which that variable will be used. So whilst a `using` can only be used for disposable objects, the point is almost always to make use of their "non-disposable" aspects within that scope.

Comment: just a nice syntaqx shortener... Specifically for these cases where you have a whole list of disposables, it would be nice to have a syntax to finally dispose them off without the need of a `finally {foreach(...x...){ x.Dispose(); }}`

Comment: Great advice. However, looking at the implementation of Process.GetProcessByName(), MS doesn't even bother to do this after enumerating every process on the machine. Process enumeration will open a ton of process handles, so you'll need to wait for a GC cycle before the IDs can be re-used.

Comment: @Mark I don't know what framework version you checked, but in 4.6.2 `Process.GetProcessesByName()` does dispose the processes that are not returned. See [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,c955a482994fbefb).

Comment: @cremor You're right - looks like they fixed it in 4.5.

Comment: To be clear, Close() will call Dispose(), right? Is it generally preferable then to call Close()?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - no, I'd prefer `Dispose` over `Close`. The relationship is the other way around in this case (`Dispose` calls `Close`). But `Dispose` will also perform a small amount of additional cleanup (such as unregistering this instance for finalization) which will leave things "cleaner".

Comment: I don't understand how can I be leaking handles, if I didn't create the process? When I created the process, I am responsible for freeing the handle (via Dispose()). If the process is external to my code, I can't free its handle without terminating the process first. I read many .NET Win32 related objects work like that - they CAN create handles, but not always. If you don't create a handle - then theoretically - dispose should do nothing.

Comment: @Harry - there's a link to the reference source a few comments up. You're welcome to look through it, and of course check the documentation. There are public methods for obtaining a handle or for enabling events, both of which call `GetProcessHandle` that, if it doesn't already have one, ends up calling either `OpenProcess` or `DuplicateHandle`. Both of these create new handles.

Comment: @Harry - and, of course, [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle): "Closing a process handle *does not terminate the associated process* or remove the process object. To remove a thread object..."

Answer (score -1):

from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.80).aspx

> Call Dispose when you are finished using the Component.
>   The Dispose method leaves the Component in an unusable state.
>   After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the Component so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the Component was occupying.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't really answer the question, it just explains what the `Dispose` method is for "in general" (which I assume that the OP already knows about).