# Main Handle and Number error in C#

Tags: c#

I try to code my first auto send key to a process which is already running.

I have a problem with list of processes: If 2 target open at same time which mean they have same MainWindowTitle then my app only sends to active windows.

Is there anyway for me to send key to that 2 target? Also the number I use in my code not working, only F1 to F12 are working.

http://pastie.org/9703763#58-59,103-112

mega.co.nz/#!O1Yx1YyR!XtDHsEHbqrj3_EzdIpC8xD0jeo_vkbmIoCnkVQbQiO0

This is my project

Comment: You need to include relevant code **in the question**, not a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste the relevant code into stackoverflow itself rather than referring to some external site.

That being said, your code is structured as follows:

1. You make a list of all window titles:

   ```
       cb_procecss.Items.Clear();
       foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
       {
           if (p.MainWindowTitle!= "")
               cb_procecss.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
       }
   ```
2. The user selects from the list, and you try to post a message to a window with that title:

   ```
       Send(key, cb_procecss.Text.ToString().Trim());
   ```
3. You get confused trying to figure out which window was selected, having not remembered the process information:

   ```
   public void Send(int Key, string _FindWindow)
   {
       IntPtr Handle = FindWindow(null, _FindWindow);
       PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, Key, 0);
   }
   ```

An alternative strategy would be to remember the process itself, then later use its [`MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property directly, for instance in some lightweight class:

```
    public class ProcessWindowWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        Process process;

        public ProcessWindowWrapper(Process process)
        {
            this.process = process;
        }

        public Process Process { get { return process; } }

        public IntPtr MainWindowHandle
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return (process == null ? IntPtr.Zero : process.MainWindowHandle);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // Process exited
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (process == null ? string.Empty : process.MainWindowTitle);
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
            Dispose(true);
            // Suppress finalization.  Since this class actually has no finalizer, this does nothing.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                var process = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.process, null);
                if (process != null)
                    process.Dispose();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Put this in the list instead of the main window title string, and your bookkeeping problems should be solved.  By overriding `ToString()` you ensure the correct title is shown in the list.

Note that you eventually should [dispose of your `Process` class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957320/what-does-process-dispose-actually-do), so this class should implement `IDisposable`, which I have done.