# Process.Start() is returning ID but process doesn't reach the Main method

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a problem with `Process.Start()` - it is returning a process PID which is indicating that the process has started correctly, but I can't see it in processes, no log nor error is recorded from the Main method. Code which is starting process:

```
public static int StartBackgroundProcess(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    int processId = INVALID_PROCESS_ID;
    try
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
            processId = p.Id;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
    }
    return processId;
}
```

NOTE: I've got the exit code:

> 2016-09-19 17:44:15 [23] DEBUG Process exit code: -1073741502

Comment: Are you sure that the started process has not exited yet when you look in task manager? E.g. it might be that the process exits quickly due to invalid args.

Comment: `Process.HasExited`, `Process.ExitCode`, `Process.ExitTime`.

Comment: Nope, it is not logging anything and it should. Exception also should be logged. Note: When i start it from cmd it works correctly.

Comment: Process exit code: -1073741502

Comment: 0xc0000142 (-1073741502) is STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED: Initialization of the dynamic link library [name] failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Looks like an incorrectly set working directory. Set `.p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to the directory where the external executable is located (or to whatever folder you use when you start the process manually).

Comment: Problem is not with directory, application is started. Problem probably is that there are a lot of applications running on the server. However when i start it from cmd it's not exitng with this error code.

Answer (score 2):

Try change the file name to something you have 100% its works. Something like "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe".

If this start, you should review your other file.

```
public static int StartBackgroundProcess(string fileName, string arguments)
        {
            int processId = INVALID_PROCESS_ID;
            try
            {
                using (Process p = new Process())
                {
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe";
                    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
                    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    p.Start();
                    processId = p.Id;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);
            }
            return processId;
        }
```

Comment: I'm sure in 100% that it is working, it's working fine when i'm starting it from cmd.

Comment: Did you run this test with another *.exe? If another *.exe run, its easier to find whats is your real problem.

Comment: I've got the problem defined, look at the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have your **Process** instance in a **using** block, so it is **disposed** right after calling Start.  According to documentation, the dispose of the Process releases *'all resources used by this process'*.  My guess was that it stops the process, but it does not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zfy9z3c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, look at [How to dispose a System.Diagnostics.Process object without killing process?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30510403/33499)

Comment: OK, than this is not the problem.