# Is there any way to 'GetCommandLineArgs' from another process?

Tags: c#, process, arguments, kill

I'm just trying to start and kill multiple instances of the same program with different arguments. Starting is not a problem but how can I kill a process with a specific argument?

```
static void Start(string args)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = { FileName = "FileName", Arguments = args }
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

This is my method to start procs with args.

I tried to reserve it somehow, but I wasn't successful. I already searched on Google for the last hour, but didn't get any helpful results.

Comment: Use a Dictionary<string, Process> to store the processes.

Comment: A dictionary will work, but if this dictionary lives/exists for a longer time, don't forget to dispose the Process objects from the dictionary if they are not useful anymore. Otherwise, your program might hold onto/leak process handles through the dictionary holding onto Process objects. (See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957320/what-does-process-dispose-actually-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<string, Process>` to store the processes and args:

```
static Dictionary<string, Process> processes = new Dictionary<string, Process>();

static void StartProcess(string args)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = { FileName = "FileName", Arguments = args }
    };
    process.Start();
    processes.Add(args, process);
}

static void StopProcess(string args)
{
    var process = processes[args];
    process.Kill();
    process.Dispose();
    processes.Remove(args);
}
```